Spring Reactive Pipeline running logic multiple times
I am building a Spring Reactive web application. Currently the logic is all working correctly but I noticed that everything is being run 3 times instead of 1.
    public Flux<PlayerPropDetail> getProps() {
        Mono<List<Projections>> currentProjections = makeAnApiCall()
                        .filter(projection -> projection.getMinutes().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0).collectList();
        Mono<List<Long>> todaysGameIds = currentProjections
                .map(gameIds -> gameIds.stream().map(Projections::getGameId).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())).log();
        return doSomeOtherStuff(todaysGameIds, currentProjections);
    }

I have added some logs and can see that doSomeOtherStuff() will get called 3 times. However, I am confused why and I am unsure of where the 3 times is coming from. The API call I am making with webclient returns a Flux with a lot of data and then I am going through that data and getting the distinct Game IDs (there is 5 distinct values there).
I am suspecting it has to do with the logic I have upstream from this method:
Flux<PlayerPropDetail> currentProps = getProps();
Flux<EvCalculationRequest> propsForEvCalculation = currentProps.flatMap(this::compareWithPreviousPropAndCreateRequests);
Flux<PlayerPropDetail> propsWithEv = propsForEvCalculation
        .filter(prop -> Objects.nonNull(prop.getPropId()))
        .buffer(200)
        .flatMap(this::calculateValueForProp);

Flux<PlayerPropDetail> finalProps = Flux.zip(propsForEvCalculation.collectList(), currentProps.collectList(), propsWithEv.collectList())
        .map(zippedPropsData -> combineAllProps(zippedPropsData))
        .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable).map(nbaPropsRepository::updateProp);

return finalProps;


Well that is what you are doing. It is reactive and hence lazy, it will only evaluate when terminated with like a collectList. You are calling propsForEvCalculation twice that with the currentProps.collectList() will make it run 3 times.

Okay so the fix is to chain all these operations together and keep passing whatever data is required between each operation? Still adjusting to the reactive style
